# How do I get Perl POD in string and print it in page?

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I have a POD document. Now, I want to convert that POD to a parsed section like usage/description and get it in a string.

Why not [`pod2usage`](http://perldoc.perl.org/pod2usage.html)?

This doesn't help me to get the output in string but in STDOUT/file. I am stressing on the point "getting it in string", because I want to display the POD in "pages" if the length exceeds screen length. [`pod2usage`](http://perldoc.perl.org/pod2usage.html) doesn't print them in pages :(

Can somebody tell me which module to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

[Pod::Usage](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html), which is referenced on the bottom of the pod2usage man page.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pod::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Pod::Parser) documentation:

> Alternatively, an IO::String object is also accepted as an output file handle.

So this is perfectly legal:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use IO::String;
use Pod::Text;
my $buffer;
my $io = IO::String->new($buffer);
my $parser= Pod::Text->new (sentence => 0, width => 78);
$parser->parse_from_file('/usr/share/perl5/Net/Jabber.pm',$io);
print $buffer;
```

On the other hand, remember that you can capture the output of any command using backticks, e.g.

```
$text = `/usr/bin/pod2usage /usr/share/perl5/Net/Jabber.pm`;
```

or `qx{}` for clarity:

```
$text = qx{/usr/bin/pod2usage /usr/share/perl5/Net/Jabber.pm};
```

Comment: `IO::String` is useful for all sorts of things.

Comment: Indeed, but if you are sure to be running in a perl5.8-or later environment, you can just use scalar references instead.

Comment: Since Pod::Text derives from Pod::Simple, you can say: `my $string; $parser->output_string(\$string);` right below your Pod::Text->new line, and then you'll get all your output written out to $string. Pod::Text makes a lot more sense than backticks/qx{} IMO, since it's cross-platform.

Comment: i am using 5.8.8 version only.. I have got all output to a string.. then to print only one section of POD(eg: synopsis), do i have to do manual parsing? or is there any modules which provides way to extract that also?

Comment: That's the exact description of Pod::Select ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do all of the Pod parsing yourself; most of it is done already with [Pod::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Pod-Simple). You can write a short subclass to do whatever you need. I have a chapter in Mastering Perl that goes into the details, but you can also look at my [Pod::Perldoc::TOC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Pod-Perldoc-TOC) module to see a short example.

Basically, you handle the =head1 elements, but skip the ones that aren't SYNOPSIS. Once you run into the right =head1, set a flag and process the section until you run into another =head1, at which point you stop parsing. You can do anything you like between the =head1's, including appending to a variable.